# Help with psensor

Tags: psensor

I just wanna know wich ones of all of this temps are my motherboard and my cpu temperatures, there's, there's a lot of stuff and i can't recognize wich of them are.. wich

[image]

Thanks and good day to yall! c:

PS: My cpu is a ryzen 3 3200g and my mobo is an assrock a320m.
PS2: If i make any mistake in english please don't correct me, ive no respect for this language

Comment: You don’t have to respect a language to want it to be accurate so others can understand you.

Comment: I'm the one making this conversation possible

Answer (score 0):

CPUTIN is your overall motherboard temperature.

Processor temperature is usually listed as Package ID0 and Psensor will list down the temperature for each physical core

it doesnt look like your psensor is listing the temperature for your CPU, maybe other more knowledgeable could provide that part of the question.

Source.

> https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/what-is-cputin.2676716/
> https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/hwmonitor-cpuid-what-is-cputin-auxtin-systin-and-tmpin3.348824/

Comment: And what's the first one? That edge, is that my actual cpu temperature?